# MongoDB aggregation: Aggregate array into keyed objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'd like to flatten document array into a keyed objects using the aggregation functionality. Here’s an example of my documents:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "texts": [
            { "language": "english", "text": "hello" },
            { "language": "german", "text": "hallo" },
            { "language": "french", "text": "bonjour" }
        ]
    }, …
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
     {
        "_id": 1,
        "texts": {
            "english": "hello",
            "german": "hallo",
            "french": "bonjour"
        }
    }, …
]
```

I’ve looked at different operators, e.g. `$map`, but this seems to be focued on transforming array to array. I’d probably need a JS equivalent of `$reduce`, but couldn’t find a way of accumulating my values into an object.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) which converts an array of k-v pairs into single object:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            texts: {
                $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$texts",
                        as: "text",
                        in: {
                            k: "$$text.language",
                            v: "$$text.text"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) with [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

Something like

```
db.col.aggregate([{
  "$project": {
    "texts":{
     "$arrayToObject":{
       "$zip": {
        "inputs": [
          "$texts.language",
          "$texts.text"
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
}])
```

Comment: Cool, even more concise. Will give it a try tomorrow and give feedback. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) aggregation in mongodb **3.4.4** and above

Just convert `language` field with key(k) and text with value(v) using [**`$map`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and transform the array to object using [**`$arrayToObject`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "texts": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$texts",
        "in": {
          "k": "$$this.language",
          "v": "$$this.text"
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "texts": { "$arrayToObject": "$texts" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Many thanks for the very rapid answer! +1 Both were exactly simultaneous and work equally well. The reason I'm accepting mickl’s answer instead of yours is, that I prefer having everything in a single pipeline stage. Cheers!

Comment: Interesting update: I'm actually still running MongoDB 3.4.6 -- still the aggregation works just fine.

Comment: not sure why so... but `$arrayToObject` has been introduced in mongodb 3.6

Comment: That's how they announced it. Mind you, that's not true. ;) It has been around since v3.4.4: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/

Comment: @dnickless oops!!! I had mistaken... thanks for comeuppance me... updated the answer

Comment: The funny thing is that on v3.6 of the documentation they claim it has been introduced as part of v3.6 - oh well... ;)

Comment: @dnickless Oh yes that made confusion to me... But I think it can be used in 3.4 :)